# JavaScript function parameter referencing object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been creating a game, similar to `agar.io`, but have noticed some strange behaviour when passing an object into a function.

I have simplified the code to highlight the problem. In the code, I pass the object `gameData` as a parameter into `update`, but when I change the parameter within the function, it passes the changes to the referenced object.

If you run the code, the `gameData` object, which is being printed to the console, will continue to increase, despite not directly changing it.

I am not sure what is going on here, I would like to understand why this happens and how to get around it. I have managed to fix it with the line

```
update({x: gameData.x, y: gameData.y})
```

but this isn't clean code, and doesn't explain the behaviour.

Regards,
Callum
Live code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdsfsdfsdfdsg/926vz5pa/7/)

```
var gameData = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

setInterval(heartbeat, 1000 /1);

function heartbeat() {
    console.log('=====================');
    update({x: gameData.x, y: gameData.y}); // doesn't update object
    update(gameData);                      // updates object
    // gameData = update(gameData);
}

function update(data) { 
    data.x += 1;
    data.y += 1;

    console.log('gameData', gameData);

    // return data;
}
```

Comment: That's the way JavaScript (and many other languages) works.  An object as a value is really a *reference* to the object. Imagine the performance implications if objects were copied when passed into functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> update({x: gameData.x, y: gameData.y});

this line creates a new object containing `x` and `y` attributes, that you pass to your `update` function, but `gameData` is a global variable you are working with. so when calling update with the new object you just created, updates the values of that new object, and they are not saved anywhere after the function call.

but

> update(gameData);

gets the gameData object as the argument and updates `x` and `y` values of the `gameData` object that is referenced to the global variable you defined at the top of your code, and when in `console.log(gameData)` you see the values in this object.

NOTE:

I don't recommend using a global variable and calling a function that does not return anything, instead you can create a function like this:

```
function update(data){
    return { x: data.x + 1, y: data.y + 1 }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
gameData = update(gameData)
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks, that makes sense. The function originally returned the object, as you can see where it's been commented out. However, I  noticed that it still functioned normally when I removed the return statement. I just couldn't figure out why it behaved in that way. Cheers...

Comment: @Callum you can mark the answer as correct if it got you the answer!
and also note that using global variables is always dangerous and can lead to some serious problems if you are trying to make a big thing

Answer (score 1):

I think this example is really interesting. I'll try to explain how it works in details.

As we see that, our codes called the `update()` function twice, however, somehow, the `gameData` object is only updated once.

Let's see:

```
function heartbeat() {
    update({x: gameData.x, y: gameData.y});  // I see this as a getter
    update(gameData);                        // I see this as a setter
}
```

For the first invocation, we actually pass the **primitive values** of `gameData.x` and `gameData.y` in form of an object. They are actually only **primitive values**, not **references**. Any actions we made on these **primitive values** will not affect the actual object which is stored somewhere in memory.

For the second invocation, we passed a **reference** of the `gameData` object, therefore, when you reassign the `gameData.x` and `gameData.y` properties to the new values, they directly affect *the actual object* in the memory. That's why we receive the new value of those properties when invoking `console.log(gameData)`.